# List in C++ by category

Tags: c++, qt, list

I'm creating a List like this:
`QList<Type> types[LastType];`
Then I resize my list:
`types[SomeType].reserve(count);`
Then later on, when I try to add a type, I do this:
`types[SomeType].append(newType);`

And it's giving me an asseration failure on operator[]. So, is it just me or i'm not supposed to be doing it like this? Is there something i'm missing? this is what the error message say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy4uA.png . Removing .reserve does not fix the problem.

Comment: You should really read up on [Qt Container Classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/containers.html)

Comment: @Styne666 I already fixed that, but thank you I'll do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming a `QList` is really a `vector` under the hood, `reserve` is the wrong call.  You're not resizing your list as you say, you are asking it to allocate space for *at least* `size` more elements.  Yes, it allocates more space, but it does not change the *size* of the list.

> In any case, a call to this function never affects the elements contained in the vector, nor the vector size (for that purposes, see vector::resize or vector::erase, which modify the vector size and content).

Sounds like you want `resize` here.

Comment: there's no resize method in QList, therefore I'll use QVector, thanks anyways. +rep (in 7 minutes as it says <,<)

Comment: Assuming `append` behaves like `push_back`, then `reserve` _is_ what the OP wants...

Comment: Okay, stupid me, I should've done that, sorry for such stupid question. Works fine with QVector

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, I wasn't sure exactly.  I saw the exception on `operator[]` and wasn't sure if `append` was actually throwing the error (via calling `operator[]` internally) or if the error was occurring somewhere else... though reading it again it seems clear enough.  I think I was wrong on assuming `QList` == `vector<T>`.